# SQL Developer only shows first 600 lines of SQL for View

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to look at the sql for a view using oracle and SQL Developer.  If I try to look at the SQL it will only show 599 lines even though it is much larger.  I've tried by opening it and looking at the sql tab, and exporting ddl to a file.  Same issue both ways.

This doesn't happen in TOAD, but I don't personally have a seat for that software and this is the only thing I've found I'd actually need TOAD for.

Comment: Which version of Oracle, and which version of SQL Developer? And how many lines do you see in say SYS.DBA_STREAMS_COLUMNS?

Comment: I see 534 lines in that view.  It ends at this line `(caseCOMMENT ON TABLE SYS.DBA_STREAMS_COLUMNS IS 'Supportability info about streams columns'`  which seems like it would need a space between comment and case to be valid.  I've tried in 12c and 11g both have same issue.  SQL Developer version 4.1.3.20

Comment: It might be useful information that this is the first line when i try to look at a view `-- Unable to render VIEW DDL for object SYS.DBA_STREAMS_COLUMNS with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator.`

Comment: I see 601 lines in SQL Developer 17.2 (DB 11.2.0.4), ending with the same line. I was hoping it would exceed the 599 lines for you too. (I don't get that warning but I understand why it's there, so it may not have been a useful test in the end anyway). Are you able to upgrade SQL Developer to the current version?

Comment: I upgraded to 17.2 and am able to see all of the code.  I guess it must have been a bug that has been fixed.  Thanks  Edit:  Actually I just see more of it, not the entire code still

Comment: I created a 1000 line view and I can see all of that in the object viewer's SQL tab. Wonder if it's the number of chars rather than lines that's an issue - does it truncate part way through a line? You might need to raise an SR...